# "your that question"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Recently I have seen a sentence in a chat room. Which is as below:

> - Are you saying I've answered your that question by ....

Is the above sentence right?
 If yes, Please explain the construction of such sentences with example.

Source:

> And are you saying I've answered your that question by chat.stackexchange.com/… [message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34848654#34848654).

Comment: It looks like the author may have switched their mind mid sentence from "answered **your** question" to "answered **that** question". Would need rest of the sentence to figure it out.

Comment: I agree with @Peter. Sounds like a typo.

Comment: @Peter This may also be possible : If there are many questions, and he is pointing it by using that. Shall I post the message here?

Comment: Or it could be an ungrammatical attempt to say something like "answered that question  of yours"?

Comment: @Sinister It would be better if you edited your question instead of putting additions in a comment. Just click on "edit" next to "share", under the tag labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Original example, is a typo, not a grammar mistake!

However let's have a look at the sentence:

> I have answered **your that question**.

The noun phrase *your that question* is ungrammatical. Noun phrases usually come in two sections, they have a Head, and they have a Determiner. In the phrase *the big dog* the word *the* is the Determiner and the Head is *big dog*.

The words *that* and *your* are both determinatives. In English we can only have one determinative in a central Determiner function. If we have two the phrase will be ungrammatical:

- *the my dog
- *my the dog
- *no my books
- *your that question

All of these are ungrammatical for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

Peter is right. It looks as if that person hesitated choosing a determiner for his sentence. If you need to combine both of them, the correct choice would be **that question of yours**.